# What am I doing incorrectly here that does leaves my accuracy as 0% in my model, even though I know my model works well on the iris data set?

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, cross-entropy

```
model = nnet(4, 2, 1)
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.1)

trainloader = Dataloader(dataset=dataset, batch_size = 15)
val_loader = Dataloader(dataset=val_dataset, batch_size = 150)
LOSS = []
accuracy = []
N_test = len(val_dataset)

def my_trainer(epochs):
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        for x,y in trainloader:
            z = model(x)
            loss = criterion(z, y)
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
            optimizer.zero_grad()
        LOSS.append(loss.item())
        correct = 0
        for x,y in val_loader:
            z = model(x)
            _, yhat = z.max(1)
            correct += (yhat == y).sum().item()
        acc = correct/N_test
        accuracy.append(acc)
    
my_trainer(5000)
```

Updated code- I should have been using CrossEntropyLoss instead of BCE as its a multiclass problem. This might have added to my error. Now I'm gettng the error

```
1D target tensor expected, multi-target not supported"
```

for the line `loss=criterion(z,y)` even though y is a 1dimensional tensor for the target. Oh well, at least the accuracy problem is solved

Comment: Is the indentation correct? If so, you're only computing it once per epoch, and perhaps you're just unlucky with the last batch?

Comment: @berriel hey you helped with my last pytorch question too! Albeit that was off my work account :) And yes Ive tried every indentation possible, haveno idea why it doesnt want to work, even though my loss does go down perfevtly

Comment: Could you run your script for a single epoch and plot the loss and accuracy for each batch?

Comment: Doing so gives me a good loss and accuracy at 0 the whole way. I think I found some errors already, i will clarify in a comment.Appreciate the assistance

Comment: @Ivan question edited to reflect last few hours of findings

Comment: Ok, can you show the model's definition most specifically are you applying an activation function on your model's output. Also, can you tell us the shapes of `x`, and `y`?

Comment: @Ivan sure, the model has 1 hidden layer, and the forward pass is x=sigmoid(self.linear1(x)) and then x=self.linear2(x), no activation on the final one. Its the iris data set, so there is 4 inputs and one output

Comment: Please edit your question with the relevant information. Thank!